# Can I use Mathematica to build a complex website?

Tags: webmathematica, webservices, formpage

I have made all of the pages in WIX. But there is one page, basically, a form page, that WIX currently don't provide dynamic feature.  Given that mathematica also is good with Data analyses in the future, now I would like to give mathematica a first trial.  I would like to build a form page that is more complex than examples from mathematica.

The following features are missing from mathematica examples, I would like to know if they are possible with Mathematica:

1. I want an add button in a form, that every click will give one more line of user entry. And this add button should be able to be formatted to have some professional look.
2. From mathematica examples, each user input on a form page is one line.  I would like to have more flexibility on that, say some line has only 1 user entry, but other lines have multiple input, like text input and drop down menu, arranged horizontally.

Another QUESTION:  if the above 1 or 2 features are not easily doable with Mathematica, is it generally a good idea to use WIX as front end, and the mathematica cloud as the backend?  The main concern is the WIX doesn't have a strong data storing and analyses support.

Will appreciate the answers if the above 2 features are possible.

Comment: I'm certain it's possible as the Wolfram Language is a complete computing language, but unless it's a fairly simple web page I think you'd hate developing a webpage with Mathematica.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Because so far it can be done with regular FormFunction and its AppearanceRules, FormLayoutFunction, RepeatingElement etc. At the end the question is how complex and if it will be a subject to scale in future.

Comment: This is really guided by what you want in the end. WiX is probably the best if you want a standard website (it's almost certainly the best tested solution). If all of your content will be made in Mathematica then it might make sense to use `FormFunction` and friends, but keep in mind that these are really intended to be one-and-done things and the cloud is still in beta and will be for at least another year or two probably.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments!  I agree with you all.  I edited my original post, in trying to answering some of your questions and be more specific on the features I need.

Comment: No you can’t - learn react+redux

Comment: @M.R.  Really?   Which one can't be done? or both?

Comment: One more questions:  Is it generally a good idea to have WIX as front end, and mathematica cloud as backend?

Comment: @user1470393 M.R. is being a bit hyperbolic. You can use Mathematica as a site builder for a complex site (that’s what I do for a number or moderately complex sites) but all the interaction and such will be JavaScript or framework based.

Comment: @user1470393 have you checked documentation of symbols I have mentioned? They still address your needs if stated in that general form. If they don't let us know why. Or please provide a detailed description of the form you want to implement, type of controls, layout etc.